How to "extrude" faces in absolute units in a non-uniform mesh
An often occurring task I am regularly faced with when modeling is to "extrude" or "inset" faces (I am sure it's the wrong term here as I don't know how to correctly name it ... yet) in non-uniform meshes, ideally in absolute units and not by scale. This is what I am talking about:
I want this ...

... to essentially become this ...

Basically the selected faces get moved inwards and another loop at the top is created, so a flat plane is forming that connects the "walls" with the inset faces.
With meshes that have a square plane I usually just extrude the selection and scale it down and then delete the excess faces on the bottom and create the bottom faces manually again. This is pretty tedious and it feels like it should be much simpler. Needless to say doing it on a mesh like in this example it takes even longer, since I have to grab and move each orthogonal face with grid snapping, as scaling on a mesh like this just doesn't work. And even if, there would be still the need to delete and recreate faces.
What's an efficient way to do this?

Use the Inset tool instead of Extrude. Press I then when you're in the modal hold Ctrl to offset the inset faces in or out. You will probably want to select the bottom face before Insetting too otherwise you'll get some non-manifold geo at the bottom. Then just snap the bottom face back down to where it was after the fact.

No idea how I never thought about insetting the ground plane and just extruding it down. So obvious ...

It depends on what you actually want to do - for this specific example in your question it basically does not matter if you use the Inset tool I with holding Ctrl like @Jakemoyo suggested or Alt+E > Extrude Faces Along Normals. Insetting will automatically get you an even offset on all sides (if the scale of the object is applied or at least uniform), with extruding along normals you can either hold Alt after starting to extrude or click S to toggle even on/off.
In both cases you will get - not non-manifold, but at least unwanted - geometry (the original bottom and faces connecting the bottom edge with the inset edges) which has to be deleted and leaves you with an open bottom so that you have to create new faces there. Here I selected the remaining original bottom, the connecting faces are lying in the same plane:

That is unless you select the bottom face(s) as well, but if you do so be aware that in this case the bottom will also move upwards by the same amount you move inwards, so if the bottom already is where it should be you have to move it back down. Here you can see with the same amount of inset like before, the bottom has come up quite a lot. But there is no unwanted geometry:

So these are the two mostly used methods and their caveats. However, if you want to do it better without moving the bottom or having to delete faces and making new ones, I suggest you try this:
Select the bottom face(s) and the bottom loop like mentioned earlier, press E to extrude but immediately right-click or Esc to abort the operation.

Be careful: you cannot see it, but the faces were already extruded. They just stay in place - this is a common problem for beginners which suddenly have duplicated geometry and do not know where it comes from. The Extrude tool is actually Extrude and Move and what you abort is just the movement after extrusion.
Anyway, now deselect the bottom faces or newly select the loop with Alt+left-click.

Then press Alt+S for the Shrink/Fatten tool to scale the loop inwards. Other than normal scaling this tool scales along the face normals simply spoken. If you would have selected the bottom as well, it would have moved upwards like before.
But now only the loop moves inwards and the bottom face gets automatically smaller since there is no duplicate geometry and it's connected with loop faces. Like with the Extrude Faces Along Normals tool, when you hold Alt while shrinking or pressing S once you can enable an even amount.

And as you asked in the question, all methods described above are not using scale factors, but absolute units (again, as long as the object scale is applied), which you can also enter while you are doing an inset or extrusion etc. or afterwards directly after finishing the operation by entering the value in the operations panel at the bottom left of the viewport. You could also enable Offset Even there if you did not do it while shrinking the loop.

Just a quick other method, the reason why I said "it depends on what you want to do": if on some object you actually do not want to extrude the complete loop inwards, but just a single face or several faces if their normals point in the same direction (that's important), you can again use the shortcut Alt+E but now choose Extrude Manifold. This way you can extrude faces inwards and the unnecessary geometry gets removed automatically.
For example, I select both faces pointing in +X direction:

After extruding manifold, the faces are moved inwards along their normals but there is no unwanted geometry left, and all vertices of the new geometry are connected with their surrounding faces. However, this can produce n-gons, just so that you know.

The "trick" here is that Extrude Manifold extrudes along normals with the option Dissolve Orthogonal Edges automatically enabled. You can enable this in the panel afterwards when you used Extrude Faces Along Normals as well, but when you extruded several faces with normals pointing in different directions, the results may become incorrect or unexpected.

How did I never think of insetting the ground plane and extruding down?! Wow, I feel kind of stupid now. It seems so obvious. Thank you!

@NumLock Oh, another method I did not mention  Yes, that's possible as well especially when this is all orthogonal geometry, there might be cases where one of the other methods work better. Another one: make a new loop cut and slide it to the existing edge loop in the center. Then select the bottom face loop and shrink it with  Alt+S.
